# XSL подключение PHP кода

Tags: xml, php, xslt

Имеется `example.xsl` , рядом `example.php` , как сделать так, чтобы в файле XSL выполнялся php скрипт(можно из файла, можно просто код, содержимое файла `example.php` - hello world)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обработчик PHP вызывается сторонними программами, например сервером. Ему передается простой текст с вставками PHP кода, который он обрабатывает и выдает уже обработанный текст на выход. Ты должен свой XSL файл как-то передать на выполнение интерпретатору PHP и получить ответ от него.